# Error when subsetting sfc objects with explicit binary predicate

Tags: r, r-sf

I don't understand why the last two examples in the following code chunk fail

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.7.2, PROJ 9.3.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

p1 <- st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 0)))
p2 <- st_sfc(st_point(c(1, 1)))

p1[p2]
#> Geometry set for 0 features 
#> Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
#> CRS:           NA
p1[p2, op = st_intersects]
#> Error in `[.default`(p1, p2, op = st_intersects): incorrect number of dimensions
p1[p2, , op = st_intersects]
#> Error in `[.default`(p1, p2, , op = st_intersects): incorrect number of dimensions
```

when the default operation specified by `[.sfc` is exactly `st_intersects`.

```r
sf:::`[.sfc`
#> function (x, i, j, ..., op = st_intersects) 
#> {
#>     if (!missing(i) && (inherits(i, "sf") || inherits(i, "sfc") || 
#>         inherits(i, "sfg"))) 
#>         i = lengths(op(x, i, ...)) != 0
#>     st_sfc(NextMethod(), crs = st_crs(x), precision = st_precision(x), 
#>         dim = if (length(x)) 
#>             class(x[[1]])[1]
#>         else "XY")
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x00000255ad682df8>
#> <environment: namespace:sf>
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Could you please help me? How should I specify the `op` parameter in the correct way when subsetting `sfc` object?

**EDIT (2024-01-23)**

Just for future reference, I want to point out that the behaviour described in this question has been adjusted/fixed/modified in the sf package. See https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2320 for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here occurs because `` `[.sfc` `` uses `NextMethod()` internally. The way this works is that the arguments you explicitly passed to `` `[.sfc` `` are passed on to the default subsetting method for lists. This is the primitive `"["` function, implemented in the C code function [`do_subset_dflt`](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/main/subset.c#L688).

Unusually for an R function, this ignores the names of any arguments (with the single exception of `drop`), and goes by order only:

```r
my_list <- list(a = 1, b = 2)

my_list[the_name_of_this_argument_is_ignored = 2]
#> $b
#> [1] 2

my_list[the_name_of_this_argument_is_ignored = 2, drop = FALSE]
#> $b
#> [1] 2
```

This even leads to the confusing result

```r
my_mat <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)

my_mat[i = 1, j = 2]
#> [1] 3

my_mat[j = 1, i = 2]
#> [1] 3
```

If the number of (non-drop) arguments exceeds the number of dimensions of our object, we get exactly your error:

```r
my_list[2, op = sf::st_intersects]
#> Error in my_list[2, op = sf::st_intersects] : 
#>   incorrect number of dimensions
```

It seems confusing that a default argument works without a problem, yet making exactly the same function call but explicitly naming the default argument throws an error. This is a result of how `NextMethod` works - it only passes on the symbols you specifically passed to the initial call, ignoring any default parameters.

The whole situation can be shown quite easily by creating a new class with its own subsetting method:

```r
test <- function(x) structure(matrix(x, 2, 2), class = "test")

`[.test` <- function(x, i, j, ..., nag = FALSE) {
  if(nag) cat("This won't work now\n")
  NextMethod()
}

x <- test(5)

x[1, 1]
#> [1] 5

x[1, 1, nag = TRUE]
#> This won't work now
#> Error in `[.default`(x, 1, 1, nag = TRUE): incorrect number of dimensions

x[1, 1, nag = FALSE]
#> Error in `[.default`(x, 1, 1, nag = FALSE): incorrect number of dimensions
```

There isn't any direct work-around for this because `[` is a primitive function. The use of `NextMethod` means that the named argument `op` is not, in fact, available for use by the end-user. Since the function is not exported and is undocumented, this is not really a bug, but it seems like a strange design decision to have `op` passed as an argument rather than hard-coding `st_intersects in the body of the function.

In the meantime, the best thing is to avoid using the `op` argument, and just using the predicate function directly:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

p1 <- st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 0)))
p2 <- st_sfc(st_point(c(1, 1)))

p1[lengths(st_intersects(p1, p2)) != 0]
#> Geometry set for 0 features 
#> Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
#> CRS:           NA
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, this is an amazing answer and a great explanation. I'm not sure if that's really a bug (since actually there is no official documentation for `sf:::[.sfc`), but maybe I will raise an issue in the sf repository anyway.

Comment: @agila ```?`[.sf` ``` has an entry where the `op` argument is documented

Comment: Yes, you're right but, AFAICT, the `op` argument in `[.sf` is handled differently and we can properly subset `sf` object with different `op`erations. `[.sf` never calls `[.sfc` specifying the `op` argument, but it simply runs `op(x, i, ...)`. Then, the real subsetting on the geom column uses only the `i` index and the subsetting on the data-frame-like structure is performed by `[.data.frame` after stripping the `sf` class:  https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/blob/0740152011057542ae809f81c52ae7639e5555c6/R/sf.R#L332-L368

Comment: Ah, you're right @agila. In that case, I guess `[.sfc` would count as an unexported, undocumented function, so there is no implication made by the authors that users _should_ be able to use the `op` argument. It's a bit odd that it's defined that way, rather than just having `st_intersects` hard-coded in the body of the function.

Comment: Interesting answer, and a food for thought! I suspect that the reason st_intersects is not hardcoded in bracket subsetting is related to why it is not hardcoded in st_join / st_filter - it is a good default, but the package authors wanted to give the end user a bit more flexibility...

Comment: @JindraLacko yes, it's a good default. Problem is, it can't be changed in `[.sfc` because that would cause an error

Comment: @JindraLacko the behaviour has been fixed/modified in the sf package, see https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2320 for more details!

Comment: @agila very nice, and watch the time to resolve  - some 4 hours... respect! :) And thank you for reporting this!